# Selecting rows from data table with filter option:RShiny

Tags: shiny

I have a data table with filter enabled and i want to read selected rows from this data table.

input$table_rows_selected works fine if the filter is not applied however once i apply filter on data then correct rowindex is not returned.

```
ui <- function(id) {
  fluidPage(
    title = "Job Tracker",

    fluidRow(
      column(width=6,
             selectInput("pickvalue", label = "Pick a Value", choices = unique(iris$Species))
      )
    ),

    br(),
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             DT::dataTableOutput("job_data")

      )

    ),
    br(),
    fluidRow(
      column(12,DT::dataTableOutput("x4"))
    )
  )

}

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
      output$job_data  <- DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(iris[iris$Species==input$pickvalue,],selection = "single")
      })

    output$x4 <- DT::renderDataTable({
      s <- input$job_data_rows_selected
      datatable(iris[s,])
    })

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To return previously selected row index you can add some `reactiveValues` to track the index like so, please note that the index is subject to data so if you select index = 4 and switch the data, the index = 4 will be applied to new data:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- function(id) {
  fluidPage(
    title = "Job Tracker",

    fluidRow(
      column(width=6,
             selectInput("pickvalue", label = "Pick a Value", choices = unique(iris$Species))
      )
    ),

    br(),
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             DT::dataTableOutput("job_data")

      )

    ),
    br(),
    fluidRow(
      column(12,DT::dataTableOutput("x4"))
    )
  )

}

server <- function(input, output, session){
  v <- reactiveValues()
  v$s <- NULL

  data <- reactive({
    iris[iris$Species==input$pickvalue,]
  })

  output$job_data  <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(data(),selection = "single")
  })

  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$job_data_rows_selected)){
      v$s <- input$job_data_rows_selected
    }
  })

  output$x4 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(data()[v$s,])
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

If you want to keep the index correctly, remove rownames:

```
 data <- reactive({
    data <- (iris[iris$Species==input$pickvalue,])
    rownames(data) <- NULL
    data
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. My problem is that when i change the species and then select any row e.g. rowindex number 15 is selected however rows_selected returns me order number of row rather than actual row index i.e. if selected row is 4th row from top it will return 4 rather than 15

Comment: Have a look at the edit, you need to put rownames to null

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful.

Comment: @AwaisHassan https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work